# how to detect chrome camera access dialog is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, camera

how i can detect google chrome camera access dialog open or not I can detect what user choose allow or deny but can't detect dialog is open or not I need show a little tip under it for that I need detect open it or not ... I open it by default but if user choose deny second time it's not open

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there's actually a way to detect if the dialog is open, but you might be able to infer that it's open. Show your tip each time you call `getUserMedia()`, and hide it on the callback or any other user interaction with your page (assumption being they denied video access if they're doing other stuff on the page)...

```
$("#tooltip").show();

navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({"video":true}, function(stream) {
    $("#tooltip").hide();
    // Do your thing.
});
```

You could also put a delay on showing the tip so it's only shown if the video stream callback doesn't happen for a specified period of time:

```
var tipTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    $("#tooltip").show();
}, 1000);

navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({"video":true}, function(stream) {
    clearTimeout(tipTimeout);
    $("#tooltip").hide();
    // Do your thing.
});
```

Hope this helps!